# On 10k Tools page, the "Highest score" question titles overlap "Lowest score" titles

Tags: bug, design, 10k-tools

The default view on the [Tools](https://stackoverflow.com/tools?tab=Stats&daterange=last30days) page looks fine, but when I click on "Highest score" under the "Questions with extreme score" heading to see the expanded list, some of the question titles overlap the "Lowest score" question titles on the right:

[image: Tools showing overlap]

This only occurs when the "30d" option (in the top right) is selected; see the free-hand red circle.  No overlap is seen with the other options: 14d, 7d, 2d, Today

I am viewing this on a large monitor (25-inch), and my browser fills the screen.

My browser is Google Chrome (Version 113.0.5672.93).

I also see the overlap on the Microsoft Edge browser (Version 112.0.1722.58).

---

When I initially checked the Chrome version, that automatically kicked off an update of Chrome; the original Version was 112.0.5615.138.

Comment: Looks like it [only happens on the "30d" sub-tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LpMs2.png). I think I (and @Lino) previously had the "Today" sub-tab selected, and that's why we couldn't repro. Also, there are other issues on that page. Namely, font size is not consistent across all titles.

Comment: @41686d6564standsw.Palestine The font size on titles is different for questions vs answers. That's [meta-tag:status-bydesign], not a bug.

Comment: .... I just noticed the entire page has a sidescroll because of the tags. :/

Comment: I mean, it's always been a bit of a neglected area of the site, in terms of design. The content within the two columns aren't restricted from overflowing outside of them. See the tags below on the very same page, they make the page scroll horizontally. This has been a "problem" for a long time, but so few people actually use it that it probably doesn't sit too high on the priority list.

Comment: Not to be picky about it but like... your monitor size (in inches) doesn't really matter - the resolution does :P I have a 27-inch monitor with a resolution of 2560×1440 pixels and I have two browser windows side-by-side and the full width of a standard SE page fits across each window :P So, yes, that is a big monitor but if it has bad resolution, you won't be able to do that :D

Comment: 10k tools need some love, overall. Too bad that it ain't happening though.